# Windows 7: How to change context menu item icon?

Tags: windows-7, registry, contextmenu

In my Wwindows 7 installation I have a context menu item for scanning stuff for viruses. This menu item is for folders as well as for files. But the icon on this menu item is ugly. Is there a way to change the icon on a context menu item by manipulating the registry and by supplying path to a file containging the desired icon (*.ico, *.exe, *.dll)?

Regrads,
Dmitri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the application.  The icon asset is probably stored in a DLL or an executable related to the application.  Most likely you will have to modify that file with a tool such as [Resource Hacker FX](http://rammichael.com/resource-hacker-fx) or [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm).

Using one of those tools you will have to inspect each EXE and DLL in the application until you find one with the icon you want to replace.

Also it's possible since it's an antivirus application it might not take too kindly having itself modified.  It might treat modifications to be a sign of a virus.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that this is not possible, at least for very long. Typically AV software monitors itself to protect against malware injecting into the trusted AV process and getting past firewalls and gaining elevated privileges. Like JasonCG says, using a resource editor would be the best bet, but then you run into the problem of it reverting if the AV updater changes the .exe (and hence the resource).

Answer (score 0):

```r
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\virus-scan]
"Icon" = "C:\\virus-scan.ico"
```

[image: context menu]